# What are the minimum specifications for a dermascope?

Tags: dermatology, home-medical-equipment, melanoma

In addition to professionally sourced dermascopes that tend to be expensive are several low end devices that connect wirelessly to a smartphone. What would be the minimum specifications of a device to produce a picture that could then be sent to a dermatologist for analysis? IE: magnification (IE: 1000x vs 200x, etc.?), lighting (number of LEDs?), megapixels (minimum?), what have you?

For example, would [the "Basic" low end version (currently $99 at Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GA9QJQY) be "a joke"? Or would it be adequate for a yes/no analysis for melanoma?

If it is inadequate, at what point do the specs become acceptable to a pro for analysis?

Note:

I expect to spend some time in a country largely dependent on telemedecine.

Comment: If you're going to be in a country without adequate modern health care, have you considered that country's internet services? High resolution photos can be very large, and upload times can be quite long over slow connections.

Comment: After giving this some thought I realized I probably would get the specs from the telemedicine office. I think I should delete this question